# Strange animation on the navigation bar during push

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I has a storyboard like below.

[image: Storyboard]

When i taped “Push ViewController 2”, a strange animation has appeared.

[image: Strange animation on navigation bar]

I set NavigationController.view.backgroundColor or  TabBarController.view.background to white. But it does not working.
I don’t want to set navigationBar.translucent to NO.

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: is this on simulator or on device too?

Comment: both simulator and device.

Comment: How are you able to embed UITabBarController into UINavigationController. I think embedding Item1 and Item2 into UINavigationController separately should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you using a NavigationController in `TabView application`. Its a common practice to embed a NavigationController separately to each of your ViewController to avoid unusual behaviour and also it gives you a better way to control your `NavigationController` in seperate instance. Following Storyboard layout fix your strange animation.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**PS:** Same idea also mentioned by **@skJosh** comment.

**Update:**
Paste below code into your `DetailViewController` to hide and unhide your TabBar.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
}
```

Comment: How you hide Tabbar?

Answer (score -1):

You don't have your view controller *(pushed within the navigation)* extended under the `navigationBar` *(That is why you see the blurred red view controller - which is the previous one - underneath the bar)*.

Set your `edgesForExtendedLayout` and `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars`. Also the `navigationBar.isTranslucent` must be `true` in this case.

Or you can just turn the `navigationBar`'s translucency off and set it's colour to whatever you want.

Comment: @oolionoo Then you are doing it wrong. Make sure that you set the view controller's lets say `edgesForExtendedLayout = .top` and the `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true`.

Answer (score -1):

set following `Animates` check to uncheck

[image]

Comment: *"I don’t want to set navigationBar.translucent to NO."*